# HTML element disappears when rotating to landscape in Safari in iOS when tab bar present

Tags: html, css, safari, viewport

This is the weirdest thing. Here's the source code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Kaely Michels-Gualtieri</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>

                   body { margin: auto }
                   #icons { margin: auto; position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 50%; height: 100px; background: black }

            </style></head>

<body>

    <span id="icons">
        <a href="/"></a>
    </span>

</body></html>
```

I'm experimenting on an iOS device running the latest, 9.3 or whatever (nothing special), and **when I orient the device with the source code provided above, the `<span>` bar disappears** (if Safari's tab bar controller is visible – AKA open tabs in the background)! If there's no other tabs, there's no problem. **Something to do with `position: fixed` elements.**

I think it has to do with the Safari's tab bar controller screwing with the viewport.

**Would love some help on this one. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be a known bug...

[bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153056](http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153056)

Found a concise solution on StackOverflow (search terms `position` `fixed` orientation). The bug appears to be WebKit specific, thus its limited to iPhone 6/s Plus and Safari. Android devices and Chrome appear to be unaffected!

Append `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` or `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` to the CSS declaration. For example,

`#icons { ... ; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) }`

I don't know that there's a difference between the two but `translateZ(0)` is shorter. I also expect `-webkit` to be unneeded.

May you be saved!

Answer (score 0):

hi @zaydek have you tried looking in to this articles

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jun/05/ipad-scroll-issues-with-fixed-content

https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution! :D